# Vuetify Jest Unknown custom element <v-*>

Tags: typescript, vue.js, jestjs, vuetify.js, ts-jest

I am writing unit tests for my project, using Jest. Project is based on Vue, Vuetify (1.5) and TypeScript (and vue-property-decorator).

I have basic wrapper for `<v-btn>`. It looks like this:

```
<template>
  <v-btn
    :round="!square"
    v-on="$listeners"
  >
    <slot />
  </v-btn>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Vue, Prop, Component } from 'vue-property-decorator';

import { VBtn } from 'vuetify/lib';

@Component({
  components: {
    VBtn,
  },
})
export default class Btn extends Vue {
  @Prop({ default: false, type: Boolean }) private square!: boolean;
}
</script>
```

And I wrote basic test, just to mount this component:

```
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import Vue from 'vue';
import Btn from './Btn.vue';

describe('Btn', () => {

  it('should render button', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(Btn, {
      propsData: {
        onClick: () => {}
      }
    });

    console.log((Vue as any).options.components.VBtn)

    console.log('=======================');
    console.log(wrapper.html());
    console.log('=======================');
  });
});
```

When running test I'm getting this error:

```
  console.error node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:621
    [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <v-btn> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

    found in

    ---> <Btn>
```

But I know that component is registered - it works when running the project (not test). Also, I have console log in test that checks if it is registered (`console.log((Vue as any).options.components.VBtn)`) and it shows that component is registered globally.

Here is my `jest.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  moduleFileExtensions: [
    "js",
    "ts",
    "json",
    "vue"
  ],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    "^@/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/$1",
    "^vuetify/lib$": "vuetify",
  },
  modulePaths: [
    "<rootDir>/src",
    "<rootDir>/node_modules"
  ],
  transform: {
    ".+\\.(css|styl|less|sass|scss|png|jpg|ttf|woff|woff2)$": "jest-transform-stub",
    "^.+\\.ts?$": "ts-jest",
    ".*\\.(vue)$": "vue-jest",
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    "<rootDir>/node_modules/(?!(vuetify)/)",
  ],
  testRegex: "(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.(js?|ts?)$",
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/tests/unit/setup.ts'],
}
```

And `setup.ts` file:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuetify from 'vuetify';

Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.use(Vuetify);
```

I was trying to move code from `setup.ts` to the test but it doesn't changed anything. I think there may be problem with `'vue-property-decorator'` but my whole project is based on it so I don't want to change it.
Can you help me? Maybe something is wrong in my Jest transform configuration?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem. Had to change two lines of code:

In my Btn component, changed VBtn import to:
`import { VBtn } from 'vuetify/lib/components/VBtn';` (imported from `vuetify/lib/components/VBtn`, not from `vuetify/lib`).

In `jest.config.js` update in `moduleNameMapper` to `'vuetify/lib(.*)': '<rootDir>/node_modules/vuetify/es5$1'`.

And that is all, now it works :)

My whole `jest.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  moduleFileExtensions: [
    "js",
    "ts",
    "json",
    "vue"
  ],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    "^@/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/$1",
    'vuetify/lib(.*)': '<rootDir>/node_modules/vuetify/es5$1',
  },
  modulePaths: [
    "<rootDir>/src",
    "<rootDir>/node_modules"
  ],
  transform: {
    ".+\\.(css|styl|less|sass|scss|png|jpg|ttf|woff|woff2)$": "jest-transform-stub",
    "^.+\\.ts?$": "ts-jest",
    ".*\\.(vue)$": "vue-jest",
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    "<rootDir>/node_modules/(?!(vuetify)/)",
  ],
  testRegex: "(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.(js?|ts?)$",
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/tests/unit/setup.ts'],
}
```

Comment: The reason this works. is because jest doesn't transpile any code because it runs in node not the browser. Any special configuration done for production and development needs to also be added to unit testing which is a totally separate pipeline.

Answer (score 26):

Create `index.js`/`index.ts` in your `tests/unit` folder with the setup below

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuetify from "vuetify";
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.use(Vuetify);
```

Update your `jest.config.js` in the root of your project

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  setupFiles: ["<rootDir>/tests/unit/index.ts"],
};
```

It looks like a autogenerated bug when generating `Vuetify` project from the `CLI`. In short, it's because `Vuetify` is not registered in your test project.

Comment: You saved my day! this solution was pretty clean and was working fine.